# How much penicillinase is needed to deactivate 125mg of amoxicillin?

Tags: pharmacology, antibiotics

How much penicillinase is needed to deactivate 125mg of amoxicillin?

Penicillinase in penase concentrate from CPC. 
20,000 Levy Units/ml/min

I need IU of 125 mg of amoxicillin.

Please note that the problem is with finding the right parameters for **amoxicillin**, not penicillin G.

My goal is to test an amoxicillin product (i.e. it contains more than just amoxicillin) so the overall problem is more complex, I wanted to keep the question focused.

I would like to know the minimal amount of [penase](http://www.cpcbiotech.it/EN/c/d/enzyme-portfolio/speciality-enzymes/penase) needed to deactivate 125mg of amoxicillin (that's the amount of amoxicillin in the product) in a reasonable amount of time, say 5 minutes. I want the minimal amount of penase because I am not sure what is its influence on bacterial growth, I am going to test that separately. Maybe I am going wrong about the whole problem?

I think that this paper could be helpful in general: [Microbiological Applications of the Inactivation of Antibiotics and Other Antimicrobial Agents](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2672.1979.tb00818.x/abstract) but it's behind a paywall and I can't access it at the moment. So far, I failed to find any other useful resources.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without a time factor. Assuming no enzyme degradation, theoretically a single enzyme molecule can do it given enough time.

Comment: Well, you could be a chap and answer the question, instead of downvoting, including factoring in the time factor - it would be just one abstraction higher than a simple number and also more valuable and informative.

Comment: This is not a homework question! It even doesn't fit the homework policy. The first two points are off the table immediately. The last point, "A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals" is obviously invalid too since it seems none of you are able to answer the question for *amoxicillin* as opposed to penicillin G.

Comment: @jkbkot You should also show some basic effort. Levy Unit is not a standard enzyme activity metric. As it seems it is used only in case of Penase. Add some of your calculation on how much penicillinase is would deactivate an equal amount of penicillin. From your question it seems you are asking others to do your calculation. The edit was useful but I suggest that you add some more details.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I agree I should have added more details from the beginning, sorry about that. I'll add more of my own research a bit later in the day, thanks.

Comment: @jkbkot Moreover, there are several types of penicillinases which would ahve different activities. I don't think CPC has mentioned the composition of their product. I am afraid you would have to do an assay to determine the activity. There are no research papers (from my quick search) also that compare activities of a given penicillinase against different penicillins. Plus, the time factor is necessary. Amoxicillin can eventually degrade spontaneously as well.

Comment: @WYSIWYG thanks, that also helps - I spent quite a bit of time going through research papers myself and haven't found any useful references. Maybe one behind a paywall, unfortunately inaccessible to me at the moment. I'll update the answer

Comment: I still think this question shows an appalling lack of effort. If you had truly replicated TomD's results as above, you should have posted them in the question to begin with, so they know you have already done it and not spent their time doing your calculations for you. Also see [this Meta answer](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/267/10456) for my opinion on this topic. Many members of the community vote to close questions for being homework if they are poorly researched and show no effort.

Comment: @MarchHo yes, I should have included a bit more information which I already admitted and said sorry. Also, sorry but appalling is too strong of a word and just adds more evidence to the hostility of this community. The question as it stands now is fine and it is also thanks to the effort of the helpful comments (which yours were not). If we are being pedants then everyone should have paid a lot more attention to the fact the question was about amoxicillin instead of assuming the poster is an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

As [March Ho](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/10456/march-ho) has pointed out, we could do with a bit more information on this one.

I am going to attempt the calculation for penicillin G, and the necessary information seems to be available.

1. From [here](http://www.cpcbiotech.it/EN/c/d/enzyme-portfolio/speciality-enzymes/penase), A Levy Unit (LU) is the amount of penicillinase that inactivates 593 IU (International Units) of Sodium Penicillin G  per minute at 25°C and pH 7.0
2. From [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2542105/) and [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_does_Penicillin_concentration_is_given_in_Units_and_not_micro_grams_per_mL), the **specific activity** of penicillin G is about 1667 Units/mg
3. I am assuming your concentrate is 20,000 Levy Units/ml (not 20,000 Levy Units/ml/min, which does not make sense to me)
4. Therefore 1 Levy Unit will inactivate (593/1667)mg, or 0.356 mg, of penicillin G per minute, pH 7.0 and 25<sup>o</sup>C
5. 2.81 Levy Units will inactivate 1 mg penicillin G under identical conditions
6. 351 Units will theoretically inactivate 125 mg penicillin G in 1 min under the conditions stated.
7. Your concentrate is 20000 Units/ml, or 20 Units per microliter.  So you will need (351/20) microlitres, or about 17.5 ul.
8. This assumes that the enzyme continues at a constant rate given by the specific activity right until the end.  This might not necessarily be the case, as one would expect the rate to slow down as the substrate concentration falls below Km.  Personally, I would use at least a 10-fold excess. 176ul - Seems a lot?

Please feel free to provide further information, or to edit the answer in any way you feel is necessary

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helps me to realize that 1) I seem to understand how to compute this myself, I actually did it for penicillin G and got the same result as you 2) the real problem is that there seems to be no IU definition for amoxicillin, or at least I'm failing to find it so I'm not sure how much penase is needed. I am actually figuring out a way to test amoxicillin - maybe I could ask about that directly too? I need to double check pharmacopoeia first though...

Comment: Now I see they say that for other penicillins one should use 20 times more penase. Is there no more specific information available?